# Any good CSS Class checker tool and general cleaner?

Tags: css

This must be a common problem with a common solution. I have a lot of CSS selectors in files, most of which might be redundant and a folder full of HTML files. I want to be able to find all redundant selectors in my CSS within this folder of HTML files. I also wouldn't mind it compressing and cleaning my CSS at the same time and maybe even telling me of where I've used stuff like gradients without adding IE or true webkit support (since I'm a lazy git).

I found (from searcing this site) http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/ but it does not work with the latest Firefox.

Does anyone know of a tool that can help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use few links as mentioning below:-

http://cdburnerxp.se/cssparse/css_optimiser.php

http://unused-css.com/

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: That unused-css.com is really really nice, I'll have to run it see what it gets me thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ive recently used this

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/

Comment: If you find anything better let us know, I'd be interested

Comment: I went with the other answer cos the unused-css was really good. That firefox extension is awesome too so I +1'd :) thanks